# select isnull (max(id),1000)+1 from Employee what is the meaning of this sql statement?

Tags: sql

Specifically I want to know why isnull is used here and why 1000 is written.please help me understanding this statement.

Comment: This statement is probably part of bogus code to assign an `id` starting at 1000 to the `id` column.  Whoever wrote it doesn't know about `serial`/`auto_increment`/`identity` columns that are the right way to implement such logic.

Comment: Specifically what the statement does is select a value that is 1 greater than the current maximum `id`. If no `id` exists then it selects `1001` instead (`1000 + 1)`. If this is part of a stored procedure, then something like `SELECT scope_identity()` (for SQL Server) be used, the code you are showing has major concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why?  Can't say.  What it does is give you the max ID + 1 if any exist or 1001 if all id columns are null.

Comment: Technically, 1001 :)